# Selecting a row in SQL Server if at least one column meets a certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming I have a list of patients with a `patient id`, some other information, and whether or not they have to take a dose of medicine every hour.

How do I select a patient only if he/she takes at least one dose during the day?

The sample data is shown here:

[image: example]

Answer (score 9):

You can simply do:

```
select t.*
from t
where 'Y' in (hour_1, hour_2, . . . , hour_24)
```

Comment: **Gordon** is always first to respond and always come with the simplest best solutions. `my observations` :) Bravo.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am ashamed of myself for not thinking of this. Thanks again!